# Unnesting in SQL (Athena): How to convert array of structs into an array of values plucked from the structs?

Tags: sql, row, avro, amazon-athena, unnest

I am taking samples from a Bayesian statistical model, serializing them with Avro, uploading them to S3, and querying them with Athena.

I need help writing a query that unnests an array in the table.

The CREATE TABLE query looks like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `model_posterior`(
  `job_id` bigint,
  `model_id` bigint,
  `parents` array<struct<`feature_name`:string,`feature_value`:bigint, `is_zid`:boolean>>,
  `posterior_samples` struct <`parameter`:string,`is_scaled`:boolean,`samples`:array<double>>)
```

The "samples" array in the "posterior_samples" column is where the samples are stored.  I have managed to unnest the "posterior_samples" struct with the following query:

```
WITH samples AS (
    SELECT model_id, parents, sample, sample_index
    FROM posterior_db.model_posterior 
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(posterior_samples.samples) WITH ORDINALITY AS t (sample, sample_index)
    WHERE job_id = 111000020709
)
SELECT * FROM samples
```

[image]

Now what I want is to unnest the parents column.  Each record in this column is an array of structs.  I am trying to create a column that just has an array of values for the "feature_value" keys in that array of structs. (The reason why I want an array is that the parents array can have a length > 1).

In other words for each array in the parents row, I want an array of the same size.  That array should contain only the values of the "feature_value" key from the structs in the original array.

Any advice on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `transform` function described [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/lambda.html).
Assuming we have table named `samples` with structure mentioned in your question. Then you can write query that looks something like as follows

```
SELECT *, transform(parents, parent -> parent.feature_value) as only_ feature_values

FROM samples
```

***Note : this many not be the perfect query syntactically but you can play with it.***

Hope this would help. Cheers :)