# Athena nested Struct Querying - how to query Value_counts in SQL

Tags: sql, ddl, amazon-athena

I have a big nested struct in AWS Athena. Here's one column named "petowners" in the table:

```
{_id=5e6b531a412345e0e86aeae0, status=NotAnalyzed, animalcategories=[{categoryname=mammals, matches=1}, {categoryname=birds, matches=2}, {categoryname= UnknownField, matches=4}], ...many-other-values}
```

I'm looking for:

1. The equivalent of the python function `value_counts` in the column.
   Meaning I'm looking for the SQL Athena command that will output for
   this row: `[mammals:1, birds:2, UnknownField:4]`
2. A way to query aggregation - to create a histogram of total number
   of pets per owner for this `row = 7`
3. How many pet owners have an `UnknownField` in 'animalycategories'
4. How many animal types are there in the entire table?

Comment: When logic becomes complex due to the data structure, you can use regex to extract the data that you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the beginning of the solution:
Let's call the table "entire_table"

```
 SELECT t.entire_table._id,
         t.petowners.animalcategories,
         ac.categoryname,
         ac.matches
FROM entire_table t, UNNEST(t.petowners.animalcategories) AS t(ac)
```

This query will output a table with columns named "categoryname" and "matches", where each row is duplicated for as many category names as there are for each user_id:

```
| _id                      | animalcategories                                                                                              | categoryname | matches |
|--------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|---------|
| 5e6b531a412345e0e86aeae0 | [{categoryname=mammals, matches=1}, {categoryname=birds, matches=2}, {categoryname= UnknownField, matches=4}] | mammals      | 1       |
| 5e6b531a412345e0e86aeae0 | [{categoryname=mammals, matches=1}, {categoryname=birds, matches=2}, {categoryname= UnknownField, matches=4}] | birds        | 2       |
| 5e6b531a412345e0e86aeae0 | [{categoryname=mammals, matches=1}, {categoryname=birds, matches=2}, {categoryname= UnknownField, matches=4}] | UnknownField | 4       |
```

And here are the most relevant links by order of importance that enabled the solution:

- [A similar question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472110/unnesting-in-sql-athena-how-to-convert-array-of-structs-into-an-array-of-valu)
- [Presto documentation showing Lambda Expressions and Functions which are another way to work with nested structs](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/lambda.html)
- [AWS explaining about "Querying Arrays with Complex Types and Nested Structures"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html)
- [A good blog read from Joe Celko about "Nesting levels in SQL"](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training/nesting-levels-in-sql/)
- [SQL original paper from 1970 IBM research by E.F.CODD added for the sake of "being pretty" and as a token of respect](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf)
- [SQL pdf HUGE manual - a bit of an overkill but under "Query expressions" at page 323 I look for the answers I can't seem to find anywhere else](http://jtc1sc32.org/doc/N1801-1850/32N1822T-text_for_ballot-CD_9075-2.pdf)

Going down the rabbit hole I encountered some less helpful links that I find worth mentioning, for the sake of this thorough review I'll add them here:

- [AWS Athena forum - many good questions, yet sadly few answers](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=242&start=0)
- [Presto google group - focused on the engineering part, not many answers as well](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/presto-users)

I hope someone someday will find this post useful and get themselves a shortcut from a few hours of browsing the web for answers I had to go through. Good luck.

Comment: Man it looks like you had to do a LOT of legwork for this one