# Athena UNION - do I need to define struct columns?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a bunch of tables in Athena that contain structs with different nested columns. I'd like to query from all of those tables as a single table (ie, a union view) and I'd like to be able to return the nested column from the struct only if it exists, otherwise return a null.

Example:

```
Table1: 
email
record: {email, first_name, last_name}

Table2:
email
record: {email, dob}
```

I'd like to be able to union those and then query on the common email column. Then do something like `record.first_name` to generate a column populated with data from Table1 rows and a null value for Table 2 rows.

I've tried wrapping a try() block around the attribute, and that resulted in a "column cannot be resolved" error.

Is this possible? Or do I need to define the struct columns in the view/union query?

Comment: One solution may be to use TRANSFORM on each element you want to extract. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472110/unnesting-in-sql-athena-how-to-convert-array-of-structs-into-an-array-of-valu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `record` as `JSON`, like this:

```
SELECT
  email,
  CAST(record AS JSON) AS record
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  email,
  CAST(record AS JSON) AS record
FROM table2
```

I'm sure you can cast to `MAP` as well, but I couldn't figure out the syntax.

Comment: Aha! I didn't know about the JSON data type. Thanks!